# Can I use my mysql database on one host and my server files on another?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have rented a hosting provider which gives me MySQL database. I would like to locally connect to that database using PHP. Please see below $dbServer property.

```
$dbServer = "localhost"; // I'm talking about this one
$dbUsername = "username";
$dbPassword = "blabla";
$dbName = "db_name";
```

How I could connect to that MySQL? What kind of URL should I put?
Let's say my domain from hosting company is - www.randomdomain.tld

Comment: You can use the IP or hostname in $dbServer variable. And make sure that both server have the mysql's port(default 3306) open for connections between them.

Comment: "nameserver" — Hostname. The nameserver itself is very unlikely to be running the MySQL service.

Comment: Where do I get that  hostname?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I somehow change localhost to an actual host link so it would work on any website?

Maybe. You would have to ensure all of these are true:

- MySQL is configured to listen on a network interface you can route to from the other computer. If it only listens on localhost (with the loopback network interface or a UNIX socket) then it won't be accessible.
- The network port it listens to must not be firewalled so that the other computer cannot access it.
- The credentials used to connect to the database must allow access from the computer you are connecting from. (It is not usually to allow access to *dbuser@localhost*).

> And if yes, where I should get that information?

`localhost` just means "this computer".

You know a hostname you can access it from because you typed it into your browser's address bar in order to access PHPMyAdmin over HTTP.

Comment: FTP hostname is web.justhost.lt but I've tried to replace localhost with that, it didn't work. What I did wrong?

Comment: @JustGalgaldas — Probably you didn't ensure that the three bullet points in the first half of this answer were true. You also used the FTP hostname instead of the PHPMyAdmin hostname.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didnt quite catch that .So my final question is is my link to phpmyadmin is http://web.justhost.lt/phpMyAdmin/ and I;ve put web.justhost.lt and it didnt work, so it means I cannot acces it that way, right?

Comment: @JustGalgaldas — Not without making configuration changes

Comment: Umm, so where do I do configurations? In phpmyadmin page?

Comment: @JustGalgaldas  — In the MySQL configuration files. You are unlikely to have access to these unless you are the server administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.
In CPanel there is an option called Remote MySQL. Your hosting provider must allow this option. You can find the documentation [here](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Remote+MySQL)

Comment: Are you talking about direct admin?